# button element's dont display when using aurelia custom element as parent

Tags: html, aurelia

I'm trying to create a custom container element to keep track of some child button elements. The problem is the buttons do not display on the web page when I do this. What am I doing wrong? I am also trying to use the aurelia @children decorator to have the buttons in my container view-model, but that doesn't seem to be working either. Please help!

If I move the button elements out of the main custom element, they appear.

My custom element view main.html

```
<template>   
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="text-align: left;">        
    </div>
</template>
```

custom view-model main.js

```
import {children} from 'aurelia-framework';
 export class main {
    @children('button') buttons;
    constructor() {
        console.log("in the main constructor");
    }
}
```

`

app.html

```
<template>
  <require from="./widgets/main"></require>
  <main>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">On</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Off</button>
  </main>      
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS ANSWER IS OUT OF DATE!!!**

Please check the Aurelia documentation for the current answer here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-content-projection

---

You need to include the `<content></content>` element in your custom element's view file. If you only want to display `button` elements that are in the content for your custom element, then use `<content select="button"></content>`

Please note that this will be changing in Aurelia RC1 to using the named slots standard that the Shadow DOM spec has changed to (though no browsers support it currently).

Here's a running example: https://gist.run/?id=4314bba289d20cf491eb82d5c620f9c0 You will note how I used the `select` attribute with css style selectors in the example. I also use the `content` element with no selector to show how it serves as a catch-all.

But yeah, this will be changing very soon. We're working on the implementation of `slot` right now.

app.html

```
<template>
  <require from="./custom-element"></require>
  <my-custom-element>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">On</button>
      <div>
        This div falls back to &lt;content&gt; since nothing more specific chooses it. <br />
        Notice how it is displayed last b/c of this.<br />
        Remove &lt;content /&gt; element in custom element and this won't be used in the rendering of the custom element.
      </div>
      <div class="footer">Footer</div>
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Off</button>
  </my-custom-element>      
</template>
```

custom-element.html

```
<template>   
    <content select="button"></content>
    <content select="div.footer"></content>
    <content></content>
</template>
```

custom-element.js

```
import {customElement, children} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('my-custom-element')
export class MyCustomElement {
  @children('button') buttons;
  constructor() {
  }

  bind() {
    console.log(this.buttons);
  }
}
```

Oh, btw, you should refrain from creating custom elements that don't have a dash in their name (`main` doesn't have a dash) if you think you might ever want to use an Aurelia custom element as a Web Component custom element.

Comment: Thanks Ashley. Can you take a look at how I am using the @children decorator? I am trying to have the container element of the buttons have a reference to those buttons in it's view-model.

Comment: The gist I posted actually logs the children buttons. I do it the `bind` callback.

Comment: The children buttons won't be available until after databinding has run.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'm at work right now and the company has blocked the gist site! I'll have to check this gist at home unless you could post the main view-model on here?

Comment: That's too bad about gist.run being blocked. I added the code to the post

Comment: Thank you for this. However, when I update my example to use your code I get an es6.promise.js:116 Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Error loading "widgets/custom-element" error in chrome. 

Commenting out the 

@children('button') buttons; 

Makes the error go away and the page loads.

Comment: I edited my code a bit after I first posted it. Check it now

Comment: Yep, getting the same es6.promise.js error unless I comment out the @children('button') buttons; line.

Comment: Please note that the behavior of Aurelia has changed since this answer was accepted.  For information on how content projection works, see the [Aurelia documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-content-projection).

Comment: @martin, I've edited the answer to mention that it's out of date and provided the link to the documentation. Thanks for reminding me!